# Need to remove all the activities inside a particular backstack?

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my problem.
I have a activities in this sequence
A->B->C->D->E->F

From activity A I need to go to activity B, then B->C->D->E, after E I need to go to activity F, but when I press back button on F it should return me to activity B, detroying all the intermediates activities from C,D,E.

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `launchmode` in your manifest file.
This blog Could help full to you [Backstack](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959)

Answer (score 0):

after open every activity you have to implement the finish() method so didn't get back stack and your app is close on the last activity back stack...